# MYSQL - Add tax to a pricefield

Tags: mysql, addition

I have a column in my table called "price". I want to show the price with VAT added in another column. Let's say the tax is 15%. I don't want to neccessarily add another column to the database.

How would the mysql command look?

I have tried:

`SELECT SUM(price) FROM mytable`

which sums up all pricefields ... I want to add 15% and then show the result in another column.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the tax added to the sum of all prices or to each price?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a view for this:

```
create vw_mytable as
    select t.*, price*(1+0.15) as PriceWithVat
    from mytable t
```

Then, you can do queries like:

```
select sum(PriceWIthVat)
from vw_mytable
```

Comment: This is a good answer! If there is the need to use the tax in many places, it may be a good idea to keep it as a constant in the db.